# XPATH to select all elements between two specific elements

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm attempting to heavily leverage XPATH in some automated Appium and Python 2.7 testing and am struggling with more complex XPATH axes to select specific groups of elements from my XML page source.

Here's the XPath Tester / Validator I'be been using: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

What I have is a dynamic UIATable that will have one or more UIATableGroup and each UIATableGroup that appears will definitely have one or more UIATableCell.

What I need to do is be able to select all of the UIATableCell within a specific UIATableGroup. Complicating things is that there may or may not be another UIATableGroup following the specific UIATableGroup I wish to target.

Here's a sample XML page source, I've simplified it with a single UIATableCell in each group:

```
        <UIATableView name="" label="" value="rows 1 to 5 of 5" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1" x="0" y="75.6875" width="375" height="590.625">
            <UIATableGroup name="Cases" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/0" x="0" y="75.6875" width="375" height="25.78125">
                <UIAStaticText name="Cases" label="Cases" value="Cases" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/0/0" x="0" y="75.6875" width="375" height="25.78125">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableGroup>
            <UIATableCell name="Case1" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/1" x="0" y="101.46875" width="375" height="90.234375">
                <UIAStaticText name="CaseName1" label="CaseName1" value="CaseName1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/1/0" x="15.234375" y="108.5" width="309.375" height="18.159378051757812">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAStaticText name="CaseSeverity1" label="CaseSeverity1" value="CaseSeverity1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/1/1" x="15.234375" y="129.0031280517578" width="62.240623474121094" height="16.3828067779541">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAStaticText name="CaseStatus1" label="CaseStatus1" value="CaseStatus1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/1/2" x="15.234375" y="148.109375" width="309.375" height="17.748043060302734">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAStaticText name="CaseName1" label="CaseName1" value="CaseName1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/1/3" x="97.3968734741211" y="129.0031280517578" width="70.3687515258789" height="16.762500762939453">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableCell>
            <UIATableGroup name="Bugs" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/2" x="0" y="191.703125" width="375" height="25.78125">
                <UIAStaticText name="Bugs" label="Bugs" value="Bugs" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/2/0" x="0" y="191.703125" width="375" height="25.78125">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableGroup>
            <UIATableCell name="Bug1" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/3" x="0" y="217.484375" width="375" height="93.75">
                <UIAStaticText name="Bug1" label="Bug1" value="Bug1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/3/0" x="15.234375" y="222.171875" width="86.07421875" height="17.7480525970459">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAStaticText name="Bug1 Description" label="Bug1 Description" value="Bug1 Description" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/3/1" x="15.234375" y="242.263671875" width="307.2620849609375" height="18.159378051757812">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAStaticText name="BugDate1" label="BugDate1" value="BugDate1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/3/2" x="15.234375" y="262.7668151855469" width="219.89291381835938" height="17.7480525970459">
                </UIAStaticText>
                <UIAStaticText name="BugSeverity1" label="BugSeverity1" value="BugSeverity1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/3/3" x="132.421875" y="222.171875" width="175.78125" height="17.7480525970459">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableCell>
            <UIATableGroup name="Videos" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/4" x="0" y="311.234375" width="375" height="25.78125">
                <UIAStaticText name="Videos" label="Videos" value="Videos" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/4/0" x="0" y="311.234375" width="375" height="25.78125">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableGroup>
            <UIATableCell name="Videos1" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/5" x="0" y="337.015625" width="375" height="51.5625">
                <UIAStaticText name="Videos1" label="Videos1" value="Videos1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/5/0" x="35.15625" y="337.015625" width="222.064453125" height="50.390625">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableCell>
            <UIATableGroup name="Feeds" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/6" x="0" y="388.578125" width="375" height="25.78125">
                <UIAStaticText name="Feeds" label="Feeds" value="Feeds" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/6/0" x="0" y="388.578125" width="375" height="25.78125">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableGroup>
            <UIATableCell name="Feeds1" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/7" x="0" y="414.359375" width="375" height="51.5625">
                <UIAStaticText name="Feeds1" label="Feeds1" value="Feeds1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/7/0" x="35.15625" y="414.359375" width="114.59180450439453" height="50.390625">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableCell>
            <UIATableGroup name="Podcasts" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/8" x="0" y="465.921875" width="375" height="25.78125">
                <UIAStaticText name="Podcasts" label="Podcasts" value="Podcasts" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/8/0" x="0" y="465.921875" width="375" height="25.78125">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableGroup>
            <UIATableCell name="Podcast1" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/9" x="0" y="491.703125" width="375" height="51.5625">
                <UIAStaticText name="Podcast1" label="Podcast1" value="Podcast1" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/1/9/0" x="35.156246185302734" y="491.703125" width="106.76951599121094" height="50.390625">
                </UIAStaticText>
            </UIATableCell>
        </UIATableView>
```

I've successfully grabbed all of the UIATableCell after a specific UIATableGroup such as "Bugs" using the following:

`//UIATableGroup[@name='Bugs']/following-sibling::UIATableCell`

However, that grabs UIATableCell in following UIATableGroups in addition to my target UIATableGroup.

What I haven't been able to do is filter out all of the other UIATableGroup's cells. My thought was that it would be easiest to bound it by the UIATableGroup that follows UIATableGroup[@name='Bugs'] and here is where I'm stuck, unable to craft the correct XPATH to do this.

It would be nice, but not required, if I could craft a single XPATH statement that would account for scenarios where there may NOT be any additional UIATableGroup displayed after my target UIATableGroup. For example, picking the "Podcasts" UIATableGroup in my sample XML.

Good times. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is kind of hard to understand. Can you be more clear: what are you getting and what did you want do get?

Comment: I want to be able to get "Bug1" (and any other bugs in that specific group) when I specify UIATableGroup[@name="Bugs"] but exclude all of the other cells from the other groups.  Or "Case1" (and any other cases in that specific group) if I specify UIATableGroup[@name="Cases"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think about it the other way round - you want all the `UIATableCell` elements whose *nearest preceding* `UIATableGroup` has a particular name, e.g.

```
//UIATableCell[preceding-sibling::UIATableGroup[1]/@name = 'Bugs']
```

Comment: That sure was simple enough. Seems to work great for all of my UIATableGroup, and whether or not there is a UIATableGroup before or after the target group. Bingo!